# Can't access a method from GameScene in another ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to access a method from my GameScene in the GameViewController but I'm getting an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping" error.

In GameScene I have:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


func pauseGame()
{
    self.view!.paused = true // to pause the game

}

}
```

and in GameViewController I have:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {


    var gscene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")

func pauseActionButton(pauseActionButton: PauseActionButton, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) {

    gscene!.pauseGame()

    print("paused! \(index)")
}

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your gscene is nil... Check your file name.

Comment: it shouldn't be, it's GameScene.swift

Comment: What can I say...? Read the docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKNode/nodeWithFileNamed: